# What is the sum of a sum?

Tags: algorithm, math, polynomial-math, computation-theory

Σ from i=1 to n of(n)(n+1)/2

What is the upper limit of computation for a give n? is it O(n^3) O(n^2)?

Example:

```
n=1 , sum =1
n=2 , sum= 1+ 1+2 ,   sum = 4
n=3, sum= 1+1+2+1+2+3, sum = 10
n=4, sum = 1 + 1+2 + 1+2+3 + 1+2+3+4 = 20
n= 5, sum = 1+ 1+2 +1+2+3 +1+2+3+4 + 1+2+3+4+5 , sum = 35 
...
n=10,  sum = ..... , sum = 220
```

etc, so what is the upper bound of this computation as a function of N? is it :

O(n^3)?

Comment: Approximate through integrating a polynomial of grade 2 (i.e. `n²`) and you get `n³`.

Comment: When n=2, the sum is (1)+(1+2), which I make 4 (not 3). Though I'm no expert.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I presume that you mean Σ<sub>1 ≤ *i* ≤ *n*</sub> *i*(*i* + 1)/2, since Σ<sub>1 ≤ *i* ≤ *n*</sub> *n*(*n* + 1)/2 is just *n*²(*n* + 1)/2, which I'm sure you could have seen for yourself.

Anyway, why should you put up with mere asymptotic growth rates when you can compute the sum exactly?

> Σ<sub>1 ≤ *i* ≤ *n*</sub> *i*(*i* + 1)/2
>
> = ½ Σ<sub>1 ≤ *i* ≤ *n*</sub> (*i*² + *i*)
>
> = ½ (*n*(*n* + 1)(2*n* + 1)/6 + *n*(*n* + 1)/2)
>
> = *n*³/6 + *n*²/2 + *n*/3

The [OEIS](http://oeis.org/) calls these numbers (1, 4, 10, 20, ...) the "[tetrahedral numbers](http://oeis.org/A000292)".

Answer (score 3):

It is O(n^3).

To see that this is true you can visualize it as a triangular pyramid.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

We can approximate `n(n+1)/2` to `n^2`. So our sum is `1^2 + 2^2 + ... + n^2`, and that is  `n(n+1)(2n+1)/6`, which can be approximated to `n^3`. So the upper bound is `n^3`.

Answer (score 1):

The exact formula for the sum is `1/6*n*(n+1)*(n+2)`, which is `O(n^3)`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, summing some polynomial of degree d over k = 1,2,...,n yields a polynomial in n of degree d+1. Since  `k(k+1) / 2` is of degree 2 in k, its sum is of degree 2 + 1 = 3 in n.

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking for *computation complexity* of the following sum, or for the *big-O bound* for the sum?

The second is O(n^3), like people already noticed, but to *compute* the sum you only need linear amount of additions and multiplications. You can regroup the summands and rewrite the sum as

```
n*1 + (n-1)*2 + ... + 1*n
```

from where it is clear that the sum can be computed in O(n).

Oh, and Gareth noted that there is closed-form expression for the sum, which computes in constant time.